# Detecting mobile visitor to website using HTACCESS

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I use the Apache code snippet from http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ to detect mobile visitors and direct them to m.mydomain.com

The RewriteRule is

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://m.mydomain.com [R,L]
```

This works if the user visits mydomain.com on their phone but if they go to mydomain.com/somepage.php then they are not redirected.

In case it is important at the start of the file is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

How can I redirect the user to the mobile version? Example: If the user visits

```
mydomain.com?somepage.php?var=value
```

they should be redirected to

```
m.mydomain.com/somepage.php?var=value
```

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: And what's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mobile redirect should be capturing and passing back-reference:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.mydomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: When I visit the site it attempts to redirect me but the page says the website has a redirect loop

Comment: No this is not complete rule, it needs all those `RewriteCond` for mobile user agent that you mentioned in question.

Comment: I have the RewriteConds